# Pylint and flake8: quality score

Tags: python, pylint, flake8

I was wondering if it was possible to get a code quality score using flake8 like pylint do by default. I cannot find the flake8 configuration for it, if it exists.

I want to be able to compare my file with this insights over the time.

Thank you!

Comment: No, `flake8` just outputs your errors, no scoring system is available.

Comment: `pylint`'s "quality score" is arbitrary anyway -- it doesn't necessarily mean anything.  flake8 does not have one and will not have one

Comment: pylint's quality score is not arbitrary : It's based on line count, the number of messages for each files, and the level of each messages (an actual error decrease the score more than a warning, that decrease the score more than, breaking a convention or a possible refactor being detected). And the level of those messages is of course not set at random.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers. I guess it is good to have both flake8 & pylint at the same time to build a more complete code quality control framework?